# In Ruby's Win32API.new, isn't 'L' the same as 'I', and what about 'N' or 'P'?

Tags: ruby, winapi

In some documentation, Ruby's Win32API has `'L'` and `'N'` to specify a "number"... and in some documentation, `'L'` is "long".  Is `'N'` deprecated, and isn't `'L'` the same as `'I'` actually?  A "number" is somewhat not so specific.

In
http://rubyforge.org/docman/view.php/85/3463/API.html#M000001

There is no specifying a boolean parameter as `'B'` or `'I'`, only the return value...

In
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/Win32API/rdoc/classes/Win32/Registry/Error.html#M001622

There is

```
 Win32API.new('kernel32.dll', 'FormatMessageA', 'LPLLPLP', 'L')
```

instead of the more common `['L', 'P', 'L', ...]` format

`hWnd` is `'L'` and therefore `'I'` will work too?  (`hWnd` is handle to window)

Boolean parameter is `'B'` and is the same as `'I'`?

So basically, we can use most things as `'I'`?  Even the `'P'` should be a 4-byte, so `'I'` should work as well?  Is there a more formal specification?

**Update:** now that I think more about `'P'`, it actually will use a Ruby's String class object, and take the content buffer part and pass it into the C function.  So using `'I'` probably won't trigger this behavior.  (example: such as using `GetWindowText()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at the [win32-api](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/win32-api/) source code, and it looks like the only difference between 'L' and 'I' is that 'L' calls `rb_num2ulong` and 'I' calls `rb_num2int` in `<ruby.h>`. So I guess the only difference is treatment as a signed value or not. 'P' also results `rb_num2ulong`, but it follows additional logic so I would probably stick to what the documentation suggests. I coudln't find any mention of 'N' in the latest version of win32-api (1.4.5), so it's probably deprecated. The Windows APIs do not return `boolean`, but some return `BOOL` which is (surprise! ) an `int`. In short, I don't think you should use 'I' for everything. The win32-api documentation is pretty scant from what I've seen. At least the source code is available for browsing.

Comment: I also saw in the README doc in the win32-api zip file about: `Removed the 'N' and 'n' prototypes. Always use 'L' for longs now.`

Answer (score 1):

L could be the same as I - but since I exists I would assume that it represents "short" (the C-Standard didn't specify the length of an "integer").
P could be the same as L - at least if you are using 32bit ruby.

Win32Api is really ugly and I would recommend against using it. You might take a look at [FFI - Foreign Function Interface](http://github.com/ffi/ffi) and the [examples](http://wiki.github.com/ffi/ffi/basic-usage) or [Windows examples](http://wiki.github.com/ffi/ffi/windows-examples).

Comment: The PickAx book for Ruby 1.9 also recommended using `DL` but i tried `gem install dl` and it doesn't exist.

Comment: `dl` should be included with ruby - try `require dl`. But the documentation for `dl` is even worse.